# Finding the wavelength of maximum absorption of Tartrazine using Fieser-Kuhn

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy, color, photochemistry, absorption

How would you use Fieser-Kuhn rules to calculate the wavelength of maximum absorption for tartrazine?

[image: tartrazine]

Fieser-Kuhn rules states that:
$\lambda_{max}=114+5M+n(48-1.7n)-16.5\ R_{endo} - 10\ R_{exo}$

1. What would $M$ be in this example? There aren't any alkyl substituents, but what I'm not sure about ring residues. Would this refer to the $\ce{SO3Na}$ and $\ce{COONa}$?
2. Would $n$, the number of conjugated double bonds be equal to 12?

[image: conDoubleBondTartrazine]

3. Does Pyrazole count as a ring for $R_{endo}$? So $R_{endo}=3$?

Or would Woodward-Fieser rules be more suitable to use in this scenario?

Comment: Have a look on [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/) for input of chemical formulae in the body of questions, answers, comments.  Said page includes a test drive to familiarize yourself with this tool, too.

Comment: Terminal -SO3Na groups have each two double bonds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fieser-Kuhn rules needs to be used to calculate the wavelength in this case, since there are more than 4 conjugated double bonds. Woodward-Fieser rules are only applicable for conjugated dienes and polyenes with upto 4-double bonds or less. [1]

```
M = 6 (SOONa, SOONa, COONa, 2 N atoms connected by triple bond,N connected to the Benzene sulfinate group)

n=12 as illustrated in the question

 = 3

=114+(5*6)+12*(48−1.78*12)−16.5*3−10*0
=425.7nm
```

This calculation matches the experimental data as seen in [2][3][4] which list the  value of tartrazine as 425nm, 427nm, 428nm respectively.

---

References:

[1] Mehta, A. (2015) Ultraviolet-visible (UV-vis) spectroscopy – Fieser-Kuhn rules to calculate wavelength of maximum absorption (lambda-max) of polyenes (with sample problems): Analytical Chemistry, PharmaXChange.info. Available at: https://pharmaxchange.info/2013/05/ultraviolet-visible-uv-vis-spectroscopy-%E2%80%93-fieser-kuhn-rules-to-calculate-wavelength-of-maximum-absorption-lambda-max-of-polyenes-with-sample-problems/ (Accessed: March 4, 2023).

[2]Gobara, Mohamed & Elsayed, Mohamed. (2016). Preparation and Characterization of PANI/TiO2 Composite for Photocatalytic Degradation of Tartrazine Dye. The International Conference on Chemical and Environmental Engineering. 8. 370-389. 10.21608/iccee.2016.35131.

[3]  Ayman A. Ali et al. (2020). Spectrophotometric determination of Tartrazine in soft drink powder and
pharmaceutical dosage form. Journal of Basic and Environmental Sciences, 7, https://jbesci.org/published/7.2.7.pdf

[4] Gobara, Mohamed & Baraka, Ahmad. (2014). Tartrazine Solution as Dosimeter for Gamma Radiation Measurement. International Letters of Chemistry, Physics and Astronomy. 33. 106-117. 10.18052/www.scipress.com/ILCPA.33.106.

Comment: References 2 and 4 are identical

Comment: @Maurice I have now corrected the references. Both the papers 2 and 4 were from the same set of authors so I had pasted same link by mistake.